# emacs macro/function for doing "gcc main.c && ./a.out" does not automatically display output buffer

Tags: shell, emacs, compilation

I'm trying to perform a one-step compile and run operation in emacs. I tried recording a macro using `C-(`, then `M-!`, then `"gcc main.c && ./a.out"`, `RET`, then `C-)`.

However, when I execute this macro with `C-x e`, the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer doesn't automatically open if I happen to not have it on my screen at the moment (even though it *is* in the buffer list, and the output *does* correctly appear in that buffer). I only see `(Type e to repeat macro)` on the bottom of my page, which has appeared *after* the output that I wanted to see, so is in a sense blocking it.

This is a minor annoyance; I would prefer that the *Shell Command Output* pop up automatically, the way it does when I manually use the `shell-command` command `M-!`, rather than requiring me to switch to that buffer manually using `C-x b`.

I also tried evaluating `(call-process "/pathtofile/a.out" )`, but that has a similar issue: I need to provide a buffername to output to, and even if I do, the output doesn't automatically get displayed; I have to manually switch to that new buffer. Additionally, `call-process` *appends* the output to that buffer, as opposed to refreshing.

How can I easily get the shell command output to show up automatically without manually performing the `M-!` command?

Update: I found out that recording a macro using `M-x compile`, then replacing the command with `gcc main.c && ./a.out` *does* automatically display the compilation result buffer when the macro is invoked using `C-x e`. If anyone has any insight to why the previous examples don't automatically display their output, I would welcome any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can specify `compile-command` as a buffer-local variable. For example, to compile, run with output to compilation buffer, removing the executable aftwerard, you can add

```
/* -*- compile-command: "gcc -std=gnu11 file-name.c && a.out && rm a.out" -*- */
```

to the first line of your file (everything between `-*-` are buffer local variables delimited by `;`). This variable is initialized when the buffer is visited. Then running `compile` will use this command. This can be a useful to specify other buffer local variables like indentation, etc. in any file/mode (where comments on the first line are acceptable).

It also often makes sense to define `compile-command` in mode hooks, eg. your `c-mode-hook`, so your compile commands are generic across major modes.

Comment: add that to the first line of what file? I'm assuming you don't mean the .c file, since `;;` is not a comment in that, and you also can't mean the .emacs file, since `;;` *is* a comment there?

Comment: are saying that if we had `;;` instead of `/* ... */`, the .c file would still successfully compile?

Comment: yeah of course, so `//` and `/*...*/` for C, but not `;;`. I was confused for a moment there.

Comment: yea I was mixing up langs

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using an elisp function instead of a macro. Putting the following in `~/.emacs`:

```
(defun c-gcc-and-run ()
  "Saves current buffer, runs gcc, and runs ./a.out if compile is successful."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (compile (concat "gcc " (buffer-file-name) " && ./a.out")))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook '(lambda () (local-set-key "\C-c\C-f" 'c-gcc-and-run))
```

Every time `c-mode` is opened for the first time, the hook automatically binds `\C-c\C-f` to `c-gcc-and-run`, which I defined, and which uses the `compile` elisp function to perform the desired commands.